# How can I know which type of the GLM is used here ? If I dont know the type of family. (consider that dependent variable nature is unknown)

Tags: r, regression

Regression analysis output on boston data. Boston dataset is used here, so I can cross check about response /target variable    but I wanted  to know if there is any other way to know by looking at below available output ONLY ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lm` uses ordinary least squares regardless of what the response variable is.  If you give it something it does not understand it will either convert it to something it does understand or else will give an error.

The `lm` below is the same model as a `glm` with the gaussian family.  (Actually `gaussian` is the default family for glm so you could omit the `family` argument below.)

```
library(MASS)
fo <- medv ~ crim

# these two represent the same model
lm(fo, data = Boston)
glm(fo, data = Boston, family = gaussian)
```

If your question is how to find out information on the columns of your data set then try:

```
str(Boston)
```

Comment: Wowww.. that was so quick.   So by default the family  will be  "gaussian"  if we are not mentioning it explicitly . Got it, I appreciate that.